# What is the best way to develop gamecenter apps with two accounts?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I am working with a friend of mine with a Xcode project that we share using bitbucket. The bundle identifier is set up on my iTunes connect his user account. When he is trying to test it he get the error that the bundle identifier is not available on developer account. Im usually developing apps alone so this I don't know what i should do. Is it possible to make a test user on iTunes connect and let him use it, or should i make a team bundle identifier? I don't wanna get him complete access to my developer account.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem to make your friend a developer or admin on your dev account, but still prevent access to the App store parts. I am doing this myself.

Comment: When I add a user to iTunes connect it said that the email is already linked to developer account. Could i enter what email I want or do it need to be an mail that exists?

Comment: I never tried reusing an email address that way. I think you need to use separate email accounts for each user, and I assume the addresses have to work.